# scanf() adds character to string

Tags: c, scanf, computer-science

I have this code and it keeps adding what ever the guesses string is to the wordle string when I compare them, resulting in them to never be the same. How can I fix this?

````
#include <string.h> 

int main() {
    char wordle[5];
    char guesses[5];
    int guess = 5;
    int value;
   
    printf("Please input a secret 5 letter word:\n");
    scanf("%s",wordle);
    

    
    while (guess != 0){
        printf("You have %d tries, please guess the word\n",guess);
        scanf("%s",guesses);
        
        value = strcmp(wordle,guesses);
        
        if (value == 0){
            printf("you win\n");
            break;
        }
        guess = guess - 1;
    }
  
    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: you have to add + 1 for the NULL character so the arrays must be 6

Comment: Beni, what should happen if `guesses[]` is too small for store all user input?

Answer (score 2):

Your program has undefined behavior. You're making two mistakes.

1. If your user enters 5 characters, it takes 6 characters to store the string. The program would attempt to write a null terminator into `wordle[5]` which is not a valid index.
2. Your user could enter any number of letters. You need to make sure they don't overflow your buffer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char wordle[6];
    char guesses[6];
    int guess = 5;
    int value;

    int chars_read;
    do {
        printf("Please input a secret 5 letter word:\n");
        chars_read = scanf("%5s%*s\n", wordle);
    } while(chars_read != 1 && strlen(wordle) != 5);
    
    while (guess != 0){
        do {
            printf("You have %d tries, please guess the word\n", guess);
            chars_read = scanf("%5s%*s\n", guesses);
        } while(chars_read != 1 && strlen(wordle) != 5);
        
        value = strcmp(wordle, guesses);
        
        if (value == 0){
            printf("you win\n");
            break;
        }
        guess = guess - 1;
    }
  
    return 0;
}
```

[See it in action](https://godbolt.org/z/Yjd78cbcK)

[scanf, fscanf, sscanf, scanf_s, fscanf_s, sscanf_s](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)

[MSC24-C. Do not use deprecated or obsolescent functions](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/MSC24-C.+Do+not+use+deprecated+or+obsolescent+functions)

Comment: scanf_s returns the number of patterns matched, not the number of characters read.  It's also only supported by microsoft compilers, so if you want to be portable to anywhere else, you need to use `scanf("%5s", wordle)`

Comment: @chris, thanks -- I'm trying to learn C. "Best practices" are leading me astray.

Comment: The `'\n'` in `scanf("%5s%*s\n"` is a poor choice  Best to eliminate.

Comment: Even the `"%*s"` is dodgy.

Comment: What's dodgy about it? I want to clear the input buffer on each read. I don't want the user to type in 20 characters and have it count as 3 words. `%*s` reads in all remaining non-whites-space characters, and the `\n` matches any white space. @chux-ReinstateMonica

Comment: "`"%*s"` reads in all remaining non-white-space characters" first consumes white-spaces and then non-white-spaces.  With input  `"abcde\nfghij\nklmno"`, `scanf("%5s%*s\n"` consumes `"abcde\nfghij\n"` when only `"abcde\n`" should be consumed.

Comment: Okay, interesting. What should it be then? Like I said, learning C here. @chux-ReinstateMonica

Comment: The best solution does not use `scanf()` at all - anywhere.  Better to read _lines_ with `fgets()`, etc.  A combination of `cnt1 = scanf("%5[^\n]%*[^\n]", wordle); cnt2 = scanf("%*1[\n]");`  with proper checking of results may do the trick depending on how one wants to report problems of no input, to much input, end-of-file, etc.

Comment: " \n matches any white space" --> and `scanf()` will not return until following non-white-space is detected - typically obliging another line of input.  Who or what text suggested appending `'\n'`?

Comment: @chux I'm not sure how you don't see that I thought adding \n was a good idea. These lines are grabbed from stdin, so end in whitespace. If that thought process doesn't make any sense at all to you, I can't help you follow. Enter this conversation with the understanding that I'm learning C. I have wrote that several times now. Don't expect everything in here to be correct.

Comment: I didn't know about `fgets()` -- that sounds like the C++ `std::getline` analog, and so would normally be the way I'd want to approach it. Thank you for that suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Your strings for wordle and guesses are too short. You need to make room for '\0'. They should be 6 bytes long not 5.

```
char wordle[6];
char guesses[6];
```